# Push code to remote Docker

Tags: node.js, git, docker, gitlab

I have a GitLab repository in which I have a node.js app with express, I want "deploy" this code to my Ubuntu Server to use the express server remotely and not only local, but I don't want install node.js instead I want try use Docker.
I have read a lot about Docker, and I had understood the fundamental thing. My question is this, if I install Docker on my Ubuntu Server, how can I "deploy" my code on Docker when I push in my repository?

Comment: There is a similar question in Software Recommendations -> https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/44768/heroku-like-deployment-git-push-and-application-management-platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have to divide the process in two steps. One is dockerizing your app, which means creating a Docker image for your repository. The second step is having your server use this image, possibly automating the process on push. So I would do something like this:

1. [Dockerize](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/) your app. This means having a `Dockerfile` where you create an image that contains your app, runs it and possibly exports a port to use it externally.
2. Run the image in your server. Your server will need to have `docker` installed, and be able to get the right image (more on this later). If only one image is being used, you can just use a simple `docker run` command. If there are more parts involved, such as a database or a webserver, I would recommend using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).
3. Make the image available on your server. You have more than one option here. You can [publish](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/push-images/) your image to a docker repository (private or public), or you can just download the repository in your server, and build the image there.
4. Lastly, you need to bind these steps. For that you need a [hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html) that reacts on commits to the server, where you send a command to the server to fetch/build the image, and run the newer version.

You have a lot of flexibility on how to do this, actually. I would start with a simpler process, where you build the image on your server, and build on top of that according to your needs.

Comment: So, Dockerize the app means create the DockerFile, and then the server that have docker installed, with the hook have to every push, pull the code and build the dockerFile again and again and again, it's right?

Comment: yeah by dockerize I mean add a `Dockerfile` and make your app runable as a docker image. Then the hook makes you get the latest version and you can just run the image inside your server. I think that setup is the easiest to start with.

Answer (score 0):

[Dokku](https://github.com/dokku/dokku) is a Docker based PaaS platform that provides *git push* deployments. It supports Heroku buildpacks to build an run your application or custom [Dockerfile deployments](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/methods/dockerfiles/).